# c++ SFINAE - checking class has typedef, why is void_t required?

Tags: c++, sfinae

```
template <class T> struct has_iterator_typedefs
{
private:
    struct __two {char dummy[2];};
    template <class U> static __two test( ... );
    template <class U> static char  test( typename __void_t<typename U::iterator_category>::type*    = NULL,    //NOTE: require __void_t , == NULL ?
                                          typename __void_t<typename U::difference_type>::type*      = NULL,
                                          typename __void_t<typename U::value_type>::type*           = NULL,
                                          typename __void_t<typename U::reference>::type*            = NULL,
                                          typename __void_t<typename U::pointer>::type*              = NULL);
public:
    static const bool value = sizeof(test<T>(0,0,0,0,0)) == 1;
};
```

This is part of libc++ code.
I understand how does void_t work, but I don't know why it is required in the context.

Why SFINAE does not work without void_t, like `typename U::iterator_category*`?

+) I think it does work w/o default argument `= NULL`, is it required?

Comment: It provides a level of indirection so the absence of the nested typedef itself doesn't cause a hard error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot have pointer to reference

```
using X = int&;
using T = X*; // fail
```

so at least `U::reference*` is pretty likely to fail.

---

I don't think `NULL`s are really necessary since the caller do provide all the value.

---

note: I'm assuming `__void_t` is the same as [`std::void_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t)

Comment: Excellent. It works properly without `void_t` except for `U::reference`.